# What's a good ipsec client for ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: 15.10, ipsec

What's a good ipsec client for ubuntu 15.10?

The vpn server is libreswan l2tp. The vpnc client for mac/windows connects on 'main' mode but vpnc is forcing 'aggressive' mode. Is it possible to turn off aggressive mode in vpnc? or is it possible to allow aggresive mode on my vpn server.

Answer (score 0):

An answer about the title: I have been using StrongSwan for the client, and this page has been helpful to me:
[StrongSwan config](https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev1/rw-psk-ipv4/)

About the "agressive mode", it is not as secure, so it is your choice. But on my netgear VPN I can choose from "agressive", "main" or "manual". I guess it is possible on your vpn server software version too.